Проблемы с датчиком температуры ЦП на материнской плате ASUS ROG X670E-E
Температура ЦП постоянно держится 11 градусов. При этом нет разницы даю я нагрузку на него, или нет. Смотрел через биос, соответственно все остальные проги выдают то же самое. Но если смотреть в AIDA64 ЦП диод, там температура существенно выше и меняется. CoreTemp тоже показывает адекватную температуру.
Процессор Ryzen 9 7950X
Версия БИОС 1807
Можете пожалуйста подсказать, что не так? Если сломан датчик температуры, почему та же AIDA и CoreTemp выдают адекватные значения?

Все ли программы используют один датчик? Пытались ли вы обновить bios до последней стабильной версии?

По поводу первого - не знаю, если подскажете как посмотреть, то буду очень благодарен. Биос сейчас думаю обновить, последняя версия 2007.

Не знаю, что за мат плата у вас. Поэтому напишите на ютубе: "как обновить биос на такой-то материнской плате", там более чем подробно расскажут, что и как делать.

Опять же, температура ЦП никак не может быть 11 градусов при вашей конфигурации, скорее всего проблема в bios, если проблема не решится, можете отвезти в сервисный центр для диагностики.

Обновил биос, ничего не поменялось, остается 11 градусов. Видимо проблема все-таки с железом

Возможно, что материнская плата неисправна. Процессор никак не может держать такие температуры, если вы, конечно, не жидким азотом его охлаждаете.
